# WCF service session is always NULL

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service. In `global.asax`, I put some data into the ASP.NET session. But when I call the WCF method, the `Session` object is always `NULL`.

This is my WCF service

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public List<Menu> GetMenus()
{
            List<Menu> menulist = new List<Menu>();

            Object[] O = HttpContext.Current.Session["menu"] as Object[];

            foreach (var item in O)
            {
                Menu menu = new Menu();
                menu.Html = ((WcfServices.Menu)(item.ToType(typeof(Menu)))).Html;
                menu.Label = ((WcfServices.Menu)(item.ToType(typeof(Menu)))).Label;
                menulist.Add(menu);
            }

            return menulist;
}

[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
                           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
                           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
List<Menu> GetMenus();
```

Here is my `global.asax` file

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     CrmHelper helper = new CrmHelper();

     if (Session["service"] == null)
     {
         IOrganizationService s = helper.CreateService(true);
         Session["service"] = s;
     }

     MobileHelper mobilehelper = new MobileHelper((IOrganizationService)Session["service"]);
     if (Session["menu"] == null)
     {
         Session["menu"] = mobilehelper.GetMainMenus();
     }
}
```

Accessing `Session["service"]` or `Session["menu"]` always returns `null` when I call the WCF service.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is: WCF is **NOT** ASP.NET !

By default, WCF does **NOT** rely on the ASP.NET runtime (and that's a *Good Thing*!!) and thus doesn't have access to the ASP.NET constructs like `Session` ...

If you need to provide some data to a WCF service, best place to put that info is a database table where the WCF service can load the information from.

If you **insist** on using ASP.NET session storage, and you don't mind that you're limiting yourself to using **only** IIS with ASP.NET as the hosting environment for your WCF service in that case, [check out this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2010/02/21/using-asp-net-sessions-from-wcf.aspx) showing exactly what you need to do to gain access to the ASP.NET session state.